# Make Consecutive animatoins in css?

Tags: css

I want a background image to exapand and then contract on hover.

```
a:hover{
  background-size: 80%;

}

a:hover{
  background-size: 85%; 
  transition: background-size 0.05s ease;
  //This is where I want the size to shrink back to it's original size.
}
```

I know there is a delay-property, but is it possible to add multiple transitions with different delays etc?

One solution I came up with is to add an additional property

```
a.workaround:hover{
  background-size: 80%; 
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}
```

However this seems like a fairly messy solution. For example it doesn't support loops and it scales poorly.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead define a CSS-Animation

See this jsFiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qDppZ/
(Only -moz for clearness)

Code:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(http://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/95329/green_button.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 80%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
}
a:hover {
    -moz-animation: anim 0.2s; /* Firefox */
}

@-moz-keyframes anim /* Firefox */
{
    0% { background-size: 80%;} 
    50% { background-size: 85%;}
    100% { background-size: 80%;}
}
```